# Database project won't drop table on publish via Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server-data-tools, database-project, visual-studio-2022, dacpac

I have a database project opened in visual studio 2022. I create a new table and when I execute my publish profile I can see in SSMS it has added the new table.

I now try to delete the table within the db project designer, rebuild solution and then attempt to execute my publish profile again.

The table is not dropped and the same is reflected in the publish script.

- I have tried with the "Register as data-tier-application" on and off.
- Within the Project settings I have also tried ticking "Drop objects in target but not in source" as suggested in [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166985/visual-studio-database-project-publish-did-not-include-drops-but-schema-compar) answer

**Publish.xml file**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="Current">
       <PropertyGroup>
          <IncludeCompositeObjects>True</IncludeCompositeObjects>
          <TargetDatabaseName>Potato.FromDacPacCreation</TargetDatabaseName>
          <DeployScriptFileName>Potato.Database.sql</DeployScriptFileName>
          <TargetConnectionString>Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=False;Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False</TargetConnectionString>
          <BlockWhenDriftDetected>False</BlockWhenDriftDetected>
          <RegisterDataTierApplication>True</RegisterDataTierApplication>
          <ProfileVersionNumber>1</ProfileVersionNumber>
       </PropertyGroup>
       <ItemGroup>
          <SqlCmdVariable Include="HostingLocationDomain">
             <Value>RandomAdAccountOmitted</Value>
          </SqlCmdVariable>
          <SqlCmdVariable Include="PasswordForAdAccount">
             <Value>DefaultTestPassword</Value>
          </SqlCmdVariable>
       </ItemGroup>
    </Project>
```

Comment: Share your publish.xml sources. And/or check different "Ignore"/"Except" options in publish configuration dialog.

Comment: What happens if you do a schema compare using the same options you have for your Publish Profile? Are there any dependencies on this object that you might be missing?

Comment: @IvanStarostin I'll be jumping on to my computer once I get back home and update the question.

Comment: @PeterSchott - My only test was that I add a completely new independent table called 'ADummyTable'. Publish - it adds the table. Then delete the table and publish again but does not delete the table. What do you by schema compare?

Comment: @PeterSchott- I've added the publish profile. I also did a schema compare between my vs database project and the target deployed database and it did indeed detect the table as a delete.

Comment: Well, `DropObjectsNotInSource` is required for sure.

Comment: @IvanStarostin - yeah I got this working earlier. The huge problem with having 1. Data-Tier Application and 2. Block changes when a drift occurs is that the 'Advanced' button is greyed out. Once I checked the "Drop objects in target but not in source" on the publish profile and not the project settings. I noticed the above 'DropObjectsNotInSource' appeared and the table did indeed drop. Feel free to put this as an answer (both the manual property and what I wrote here).

Comment: If you look at the "report" when you publish, what do you see?  You should have indications of what's there and what's not. If this is a simple design, my next step might be to find the generated dacpac, extract it with a ZIP tool of some sort (or rename to a .zip file) then look at the really large XML part to see if your deleted object shows up in that build xml. Either the report or the schema xml should give a little more detail, but not sure why it's not registering as a proper delete if the schema compare shows it as a delete.

Comment: @PeterSchott It has now started to delete, I had to turn on the 'DropObjectsNotInSource' option in the Publish config. By the way, probably off topic but I actually used a fork of your blog to generate users/logins/role permissions which worked well. I think your original blog post download has stopped working.

Comment: I just updated the blog posts - the link should work now for users/roles/permissions. I appreciate you letting me know. :)

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran into this very issue. I solved this by:

1. Right clicking the sql project and selecting "Publish..."
2. Clicking on "Advanced..."
3. Selecting the second tab named "Drop"
4. Checking the "Drop objects in target but not in source" checkbox
5. Scan options below and Enable any option you want to NOT DROP (e.i. Check: "Do not drop permissions")
6. Click "OK" and continue like normal

Be wary when generating the script or continuing to publish this by spending some time on step 5. I accidentally deleted my apps user permission and dev was down for a but until I figured it out.

Comment: why the hell microsoft is making this option to begin . I dont know. They could have desinged a better way to address by asking people when publish if they want to drop or not vs people banging their head till they figure out its  a check box out of hundreds of check boxes in their advanced setting. Microsoft always aspire to confuse users and over complicate stuff. Thanks Microsoft!!!~!